# Why and how to fix ASP MVC model validation for child entities is called but not for parent entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, model-validation

I am using [IValidatableObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject) validation for entities with e.g. following code:

```
public class OuterObj : IValidatableObject
{    
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<InnerObj> InnerObjList { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (this.ID <= 0)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("", new[] { nameof(this.ID) });
        }
    }
}

public class InnerObj : IValidatableObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (this.ID <= 0)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("", new[] { nameof(this.ID) });
        }
    }
}
```

In this case when I am validating the outerObj, when there are innerObj present it validates only the innerobj and not the outerobj. It doesn't reach the outerobj validate method in case of presence of innerobj.

I would like to validate both when innerobj present. Please help me with how its done. Why does it not validate the outerobj?

Answer (score -1):

MVC 5.2.3

If the parent class has properties with [validation attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute), and any of those properties have been evaluated as *invalid*, then the [`IValidatableObject.Validate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.validate) implementation **will not be invoked** on the parent class.

This seems to be some sort of short-cutting that MVC is performing for model validation.

Your example does not show validation attribute(s) in the parent class - I'm assuming they were left out.

The workaround is remove [validation attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute) on properties in the parent class, and only implement validation in the parent class through the [`IValidatableObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject) interface.

Comment: If I use only IValidatableObject on both the parent and child object (with no attributes whatsoever) in MVC 5.2.3, the behaviour is still the same.